# Error Executing update ERR_UPDATEQUERY in Yellowfin 7.1 Installer

Tags: postgresql

[image]

I am getting an error while exposing my database source to yellowfin 7.1 Installer . I have searched a lot in google .But I can't get clear. Also i am using PostGreSql . I dont know where to add all previleges to corresponding role or username in Postgresql.

So please guide me where do I add all previleges in Postgresql.

Comment: You should be posting this with the UI application (YellowFin?) instead. It doesn't look like a PostgreSQL expert could help you here.

Comment: @RobinsTharakan first of all sorry for that one , also I dont have access  to see database in my firm .thats why I posted like that.

Comment: DO you have any experience in yellowFin Installer ? man

Comment: Sorry, but that is a negative. Don't know much about that. Probably product's mailing list would be a better bet.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge on what ur talking Product mailing lists  als there is no tag for Yellow Fin Installer .?

Comment: When I say Product Mailing List, I don't mean StackOverflow.. I was talking about going to the Company's website (https://www.yellowfinbi.com) and going to their Product Support and raising this issue with them.

Comment: okay Thanks a lot man !!!